# FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

After updating my `Numpy` and `Tensorflow` I am getting these kind of warnings. I had already tried [these](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9673), but nothing works, every suggestion will be appreciated.

```
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
2018-01-19 17:11:38.695932: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
```

Comment: Any updates on this? Managed to solve it, I am getting the same warnings

Comment: yes see @raja answer

Comment: `pip install h5py==2.8.0rc1` (better solution than the accepted answer)

Comment: @Hooked: how does it actually fix the code? Curious to know how did you find this solution. Thanks

Comment: Can anybody say WHY it happens (and give a minimal code example), or will it just be `pip install -U ...` and `import warnings; warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")` all over again? Maybe someone would like to know what this warning tells us?

Comment: The `tensorflow` tag is not really relevant - it's a numpy-related error which sometimes comes up with many 3-rd party libraries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had tried with these and it had solved same problem for me , just put these at top of your code

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="3"
```

Comment: exact solution!

Comment: This cannot be a solution in for the long run!

Comment: Yes this will dial down the logs, but the answer does not explain the problem or how to fix it.

Answer (score 66):

This might or might not be your case, but the same warning is also spit out from `h5py` package:

> `/home/user/bin/conda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34`:
>   FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from
>   `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated
>   as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.   from ._conv import
>   register_converters as _register_converters

For anyone coming here with *this* problem, it is a [known h5py issue](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/974), introduced with [numpy 1.14](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/9505). As stated by the devs:

> You can ignore the warning, it's not going to cause any issues at the
>   moment, but you should upgrade to the next release of h5py when it
>   becomes available.

... so it's harmless. The fix has just been [merged](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/926) to master. But until the update is released, the workaround is to downgrade numpy to a previous version:

```
pip install numpy==1.13.0
```

**Update**: `h5py` [has released](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/974#issuecomment-374921792) the RC build with the fix. The following command should do it:

```
pip install h5py==2.8.0rc1
```

**Update (FINAL)**: there's a full-fledged release now. So you can simply run:

```
pip install --upgrade h5py
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma if you are using tensorflow >= 1.5.0 and python 3.6, it might require numpy 1.13+ (see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16488), so one has to be careful with picking numpy version. Right now, 1.13.0 seems the optimal choice. If tensorflow < 1.5.0, numpy version doesn't really matter

Comment: even i have latest version of all these frameworks but it was giving me same warning

Comment: @ShubhamSharma the answer suggests to **downgrade** numpy, not get the latest versions

Comment: The update for h5py is now available, ref @ClaudeCOULOME's answer for a direct upgrade.

Comment: @Maxim can you take a look at this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926940/5904928 why there is huge difference between lstm final output vs state output.

Answer (score 23):

You could upgrade h5py

```
pip install --upgrade h5py
```

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a version conflict between h5py and numpy. All you need to do is degrade your numpy version through command as below:

```
pip install numpy==1.13.0
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked in my case and I did not want to downgrade any package.

There is a straightforward solution on [Github](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/995), just suppress the warning:

```
import warnings
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=FutureWarning)
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    import h5py as h5py
```

and then import whatever package causes the error (`numpy, tensorflow, h5py`) **within the scope** of the `with` statement

Comment: I did the same as you suggested and it did not work for me.

Comment: Are you’re not reimporting the package somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following code to have the warning lines erased from the terminal by using the following lines at the beginning of your code.

#### Code With warning:

`import numpy as np, sys, tensorflow as tf
print('\nStart of Code...\n')`

#### Output:

`FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from float to np.floating is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters`

`Start of Code...`

#### Code with Warning Erased:

`import numpy as np, sys, tensorflow as tf
for i in range(3):    # Add this for loop.
    sys.stdout.write('\033[F') # Back to previous line.
    sys.stdout.write('\033[K') # Clear line.`

`print('\nStart of Code...\n')`

#### Output:

`Start of Code...`

Comment: I suppose this can be useful but it's not a very clean answear... errors are there to show something is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to find out the cause first (most answers here work for specific scenarios - libraries using deprecated features - in this case of NumPy).

## Root cause

In short, something did call:

`np.issubdtype(something, float)`

instead of:

`np.issubdtype(something, np.floating)`

This is done in assertions and logic dispatching code, which is rarely written by end users. So - often this will be something done by a library you're using.

## How to proceed

So you should find out what caused this warning. You'll use the `warnings` module, but in an opposite way than in other answers:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('error')
# run rest of your code here
```

This will give you not just the warning, but an error and stack trace. Then - you're golden:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File (...)
     # user code snipped...
  File "C:\...\site-packages\vtk\util\numpy_support.py", line 137, in numpy_to_vtk
    assert not numpy.issubdtype(z.dtype, complex), \
  File "C:\...\site-packages\numpy\core\numerictypes.py", line 422, in issubdtype
    FutureWarning, stacklevel=2
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `complex` to `np.complexfloating` is deprecated. 
  In future, it will be treated as `np.complex128 == np.dtype(complex).type`.
```

Here you see that it was VTK this time. Which of course is unlikely to be your specific problem, but after knowing what raises this warning you can do many useful things:

- silence the warning in the right place (right before calling out of your code), then restore all warnings
- look for an updated version of a library, which has this fixed
- maybe report an issue for the library which has the problem
- if the issue is there, but no fix: write the fix and create a pull request
- make the world a better place.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for helping me locate the root cause..

Answer (score 2):

Previously i was getting same error , i just had used warnings() module . I had used these code after your all imports,

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '.*do not.*',)
```

Comment: As a warning note, this will only suppress the warnings that are shown, it will not actually solve the situation that is causing that warning; it will just hide it.

Comment: Yeah Its the fix for now. I believe with the new library update will have the fix in place and the warning will not be raised. So pretty neat quick fix. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade scipy to rif of from this warning. To do this you may use pip to upgrade scipy.

```
**sudo pip install --upgrade scipy**
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by installing/reinstalling ipykernel:

```
pip3 install --upgrade ipykernel
```

If you have different pip of course us that one

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade h5py and numpy version should be <1.17:

```
pip install --upgrade h5py
pip install "numpy<1.17"
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer.