# How to solve RuntimeWarning and FutureWarning while importing tensorflow in Amazon deep learning AMI?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, anaconda

When I import tensorflow in python, I get these warnings every time. Can someone help me in resolving them?

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
```

I am running Ubuntu OS in latest amazon deep learning AMI.

Comment: The `FutureWarning` is a known (and already solved) problem of `h5py`'s usage of `numpy` functions. You'll need to wait for their next release to update it and remove the warning, until then you can ignore it safely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from \`float\` to \`np.floating\` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340392/futurewarning-conversion-of-the-second-argument-of-issubdtype-from-float-to)

Answer (score 1):

you can try latest dlami v20.0 which comes with Tensorflow 1.12, this warning disappears there.