# how to remove gensim warning about use Word2vec gensim\matutils.py:737

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I found a warning about `word2vec.similarity()` as follows:

```
>d:\python\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py:737: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `int` to `np.signedinteger` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.int32 == np.dtype(int).type`.
  if np.issubdtype(vec.dtype, np.int):
```

what can I do to remove this warning?

Comment: Hello @user10288763. This question has been answered in [FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from float to np.floating is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340392/futurewarning-conversion-of-the-second-argument-of-issubdtype-from-float-to)

Answer (score 0):

```
import warnings  
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore',category=UserWarning,module='gensim')  
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore',category=FutureWarning,module='gensim')
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question but adding an explanation of the code would be helpful to future readers.