# Future Warning while importing tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I just started to learn tensorflow and happened to get through a *Future Warning* generated by the IPython console.

Here's the block of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x1 = tf.constant(4)
print(x1)
```

I saved it with the name *"hello.py"* and executed it on IPython console line by line.

The command gets executed successfully, but ends up with a warning.

```
Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 28 2018, 19:44:12) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
C:\Users\singh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters

In [2]: x1 = tf.constant(4)

In [3]: print(x1)
Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

I can't understand why am I getting this warning. Is there any way to fix this?

Tensorflow version: *1.10.2*
Python IDE: *Spyder (Anaconda)*
OS: *Windows 10 x64*

Comment: I can't figure out the cause of this warning ;-P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from \`float\` to \`np.floating\` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340392/futurewarning-conversion-of-the-second-argument-of-issubdtype-from-float-to)

Answer (score -1):

use this command line
pip install h5py==2.8.0rc1
there maybe something wrong with package h5py,just upgrade it can solve your problem